# Не могу получить доступ к переменным класса. PyQT, ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pyqt5, concurrency

Вопрос наверняка глупый, и очевидный для всех, кто имеет хоть какое-то представление об ООП, однако у меня он вызывает некоторые проблемы.
Класс `MyAsyncCheckUrls(QThread)` получает `urls` издалека (интерфейса PyQT), через   `self.thread.urls = urls`. Внутри `def __init__` мы присваиваем `using_urls = urls`, чтобы методы класса имели к нему доступ **(раньше и имели, когда была одна-единственная функция без всяких `with`, я просто понаписал тут, новое попробовать).**

```
about_check_url = pyqtSignal(str)
```

тут тоже понятно зачем. И к нему в той, вышеописанной версии проекта, доступ тоже имелся **(всё ещё из той единственной функции)**

Проблема моя, как уже сказано в заголовке, заключается в том, что я  ̶и̶д̶и̶о̶т̶
 не могу получить объекты из класса. Конкретно в следующих местах:

```
MyAsyncCheckUrls.about_check_url.emit('{}------{}'.format(url, code))
```

в последней строчке приведенного кода, и

```
future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in MyAsyncCheckUrls.using_urls}
```

в последнем блоке приведенного кода.

`MyAsyncCheckUrls.` я дописал для того, чтобы было проще найти (тут, в вопросе) данные элементы в коде. Как с ним, так и без них не работает. Если добавить табуляцию и перенести нижний блок в тело функции `load_url` то, понятное дело, работать тоже ничего не будет (ошибка `unindent does not match any outer indentation level`)

В общем, надеюсь на Вас, господа. Параллельно продолжу гуглить, конечно, но я не впервые с таким сталкиваюсь, и всё ещё не понял как раньше преодолевал **(скорее всего костылями и хорошим куском неосознанного быдлокода)** данную проблему.

Ниже, собственно, этот самый класс.

(А, ну и если делать субкласс и наследовать, то привет рекурсия, я попробовал)

```
class MyAsyncCheckUrls(QThread):
    about_check_url = pyqtSignal(str)  # Проверка ответов
    good_requested_url = pyqtSignal(str)  # Запись хороших ответов
    bad_requested_url = pyqtSignal(str)  # Запись плохих ответов
    status_bar_info = pyqtSignal(int)  # Контроль прогресс-бара

    def __init__(self,urls):
        super().__init__()
        using_urls = urls



    def load_url(url):
            with requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False) as shit:
                return shit.status_code()


    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in MyAsyncCheckUrls.using_urls}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                    data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                        load_url(url).code = str(exc)
            else:
                code = load_url(url).shit.status_code
                MyAsyncCheckUrls.about_check_url.emit('{}------{}'.format(url, code))
```

P.S. А, ну и существует вероятность, что `ThreadPoolExecutor` не будет работать в `QThread` (чего я вполне ожидаю). Если вы вдруг знаете, что это так, очень прошу предупредить (и желательно посоветовать как обойти). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: это не класс. Продумайте сначала интерфейс класса, то есть как его будут использовать в будущем клиенты и напишите простой класс заглушку который этот интерфейс демонстрирует. Тогда будет более понятно что вам нужно

Comment: @AndrioSkur а почему это не класс? Что тогда? 

Получается, мне нужно написать класс с методами, сделать наследный пустой, и оттуда эти методы вызвать?

Я предупреждал, что я не очень силён в ООП :D

Comment: Нет. Сначала вам нужно определиться зачем вам класс. Что вы хотите с ним дальше после написания делать? Покажите пример его использования что-ли

Comment: @AndrioSkur Класс у меня исполняет роль потока `QThread`. В нём я хочу получать ответы серверов, обрабатывать их, выводить в соответствующие места, обновлять прогресс-бар и при помощи сигналов отправлять в UI PyQt (это все последовательно), для вывода пользователю. В таком виде, через чистый стандартный `QThread` без прикруток - всё работает. Но медленно. Сначала хотел через `Asyncio`, но сказали что так не сработает, и асинхронные потоки стоит делать через `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. Его, собственно, и прикручиваю. Рабочий пример класса есть только в старом варианте.

Comment: @AndrioSkur отдельный поток нужен, чтобы не фризился пользовательский интерфейс.